# How the write css transition in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a css transition but I'm unable to write it in JQuery.Could anyone help me out.
Here is the html:

```
<body class="icons">
  <div class="icon-images">
    <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp" aria-     hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.icons{
  background-color:#DF3713;
  height:100%;
  weight:100%;
}

.icon-images{
  background-color:#198493;
  margin-top:5%;
  margin-left:25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  //border-radius:;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.icon-images:hover{
  background-color:yellow;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

#### [Demo](http://codepen.io/VijayVj7/pen/BWZjYj)

Comment: Why do you want to write transition in script?

Answer (score 1):

you want to trigger the hover event from the code?

```
$(".icon-images").hover();
```

Comment: what do you mean transition code?
you want the same effect you're getting from css but in jquery?

Comment: @VijayVj try using `css()` function by jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
$('.icon-images').hover(function() {
    $( this ).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    $( this ).css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
    $( this ).css('transition', 'background-color 0.5s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out');
  }, function() {
    $( this ).css('background-color', '#198493');
    $( this ).css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
  }
);
```

```css
.icons{
  background-color:#DF3713;
  height:100%;
  weight:100%;
}

.icon-images{
  background-color:#198493;
  margin-top:5%;
  margin-left:25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  //border-radius:;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-images">
    <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp" aria-     hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done, but i believe the problem was that his codepen snipped did not reference the Jquery library. Because his Jquery events were not fired. :) 
Upvoted for nice minimal code.

Comment: Yes i did, i went on his Demo and saw he has attempted to write jquery. So instead of spoon feeding him with the solution i just suggested why his jquery was not working. 
BTW it was me who upvoted your answer for being clean and crisp.

Comment: To me clearly Elie Nassif wanted a solution in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I checked you link, the only problem on it was that your JS was not referencing the jQuery Library. To do that on codepen, click the "Gear" button next to "JS" and then in the overlay menu select "Jquery" from the "Quick add".

So basically, even though all the jQuery you were writing was correct, it was not running because the jQuery source was not referenced in the HTML document.

Here is a working solution to your problem.

```
[Fiddle Solution][1]
```

Explore jQuery functions to add a similar onfocusout event to rotate it back to its normal form.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you..!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon-images').hover(function(){
     $(this).css({'background-color':'yellow','transform':'rotate(130deg)'});
  },function(){$(this).css({'background-color':'#198493','transform':'rotate(0)'})});
});
```

```css
.icon-images{
  background-color:#198493;
  margin-top:5%;
  margin-left:25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-images">
    <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set transition using jQuery, Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon-images").css({
        transition : 'background-color 0.5s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out'

    });
});
```

Check out the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/hur66rc6/